# Shell script: Move folders + preserve structure

Tags: macos, bash, folders, command-line, error

### My goal

I organize my projects into folders. These folders all live in my `Completed projects` folder. I am beginning to archive them into an `Archived Projects` folder, and I want to archive them in sub-folders by client. I always use the client name in the project folder name. For example, I have project folders named `Appeal [May 2014] - Development` and `Identity Package [2014] - Communications`. (My internal clients are department names: Academics, Communications, Development...) Here's how I want them to be archived:

```
Archived Projects >> Development >> Appeal [May 2014] - Development
Archived Projects >> Communications >> Identity Package [2014] - Communications
```

Each project folder also has a unique set of sub-folders. I want to preserve that structure.

### My approach

I have been selecting one client at a time, using this script:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Go to the Completed Projects folder.

cd /Volumes/communications/Projects/Completed\ Projects/

# Find a folder with a specified string (e.g. "Academics") in its name.
# Move (not copy) the folder to its corresponding sub-folder of the Archived Projects folder. (e.g. /Academics)

find . -type d | while read folder ; do
if [[ "$folder" = *Academics* ]]; then
    echo "Moving $folder";
    mv "$folder" /Volumes/communications/Projects/Archived\ Projects/Academics/;
fi
done
```

I have been calling the script like by navigating, in the Terminal, to the directory with my scripts by typing `cd ~/Dropbox/scripts` ↩ `./move_project_academics.sh` ↩

### My problem

The rudimentary pattern-matching works, but `mv` is throwing an error:

```
mv: rename /Appeal [May 2014] - Development/SUB1/SUB2 to
/dest/Archived Projects/Development/SUB2: No such file or directory.
```

Clearly I'm giving it the wrong set of instructions. (Although, oddly enough, this script has worked *some of the time*.) SUB2 does not belong in `/dest/Archived Projects/Development/` at all. SUB2 should be nested inside of SUB1, which should be nested inside of the project folder.

### My questions

What shell command would move a folder and preserve its internal structure? And how might it select a folder by client name?

---

*By request, here is the entire output printed to the Terminal:*

`n$ ./move_project_academics.sh 
Moving ./[2013.04.05] - Audio - Academics - Course - Stephanie Hubach - Disability Ministry -
mv: rename ./[2013.04.05] - Audio - Academics - Course - Stephanie Hubach - Disability Ministry - to /Volumes/communications/Projects/Archived Projects/Academics/[2013.04.05] - Audio - Academics - Course - Stephanie Hubach - Disability Ministry -: No such file or directory
Moving ./[2013.04.05] - Audio - Academics - Course - Stephanie Hubach - Disability Ministry - /Documentation
Moving ./[2013.04.05] - Audio - Academics - Course - Stephanie Hubach - Disability Ministry - /Documentation/Contracts
mv: rename ./[2013.04.05] - Audio - Academics - Course - Stephanie Hubach - Disability Ministry - /Documentation/Contracts to /Volumes/communications/Projects/Archived Projects/Academics/Contracts: No such file or directory
Moving ./[2013.04.05] - Audio - Academics - Course - Stephanie Hubach - Disability Ministry - /Documentation/Correspondence
mv: rename ./[2013.04.05] - Audio - Academics - Course - Stephanie Hubach - Disability Ministry - /Documentation/Correspondence to /Volumes/communications/Projects/Archived Projects/Academics/Correspondence: No such file or directory
Moving ./[2013.04.05] - Audio - Academics - Course - Stephanie Hubach - Disability Ministry - /Documentation/Invoices
mv: rename ./[2013.04.05] - Audio - Academics - Course - Stephanie Hubach - Disability Ministry - /Documentation/Invoices to /Volumes/communications/Projects/Archived Projects/Academics/Invoices: No such file or directory
Moving ./[2013.04.05] - Audio - Academics - Course - Stephanie Hubach - Disability Ministry - /Documentation/Planning Documents
mv: rename ./[2013.04.05] - Audio - Academics - Course - Stephanie Hubach - Disability Ministry - /Documentation/Planning Documents to /Volumes/communications/Projects/Archived Projects/Academics/Planning Documents: No such file or directory
Moving ./[2013.04.05] - Audio - Academics - Course - Stephanie Hubach - Disability Ministry - /Documentation/Quotes
mv: rename ./[2013.04.05] - Audio - Academics - Course - Stephanie Hubach - Disability Ministry - /Documentation/Quotes to /Volumes/communications/Projects/Archived Projects/Academics/Quotes: No such file or directory
Moving ./[2013.04.05] - Audio - Academics - Course - Stephanie Hubach - Disability Ministry - /Drafts
Moving ./[2013.04.05] - Audio - Academics - Course - Stephanie Hubach - Disability Ministry - /Drafts/[2013.04.05] - Audio - Academics - Course - Stephanie Hubach - Disability Ministry
mv: rename ./[2013.04.05] - Audio - Academics - Course - Stephanie Hubach - Disability Ministry - /Drafts/[2013.04.05] - Audio - Academics - Course - Stephanie Hubach - Disability Ministry to /Volumes/communications/Projects/Archived Projects/Academics/[2013.04.05] - Audio - Academics - Course - Stephanie Hubach - Disability Ministry: No such file or directory
Moving ./[2013.04.05] - Audio - Academics - Course - Stephanie Hubach - Disability Ministry - /Drafts/[2013.04.05] - Audio - Academics - Course - Stephanie Hubach - Disability Ministry/Audio Files
mv: rename ./[2013.04.05] - Audio - Academics - Course - Stephanie Hubach - Disability Ministry - /Drafts/[2013.04.05] - Audio - Academics - Course - Stephanie Hubach - Disability Ministry/Audio Files to /Volumes/communications/Projects/Archived Projects/Academics/Audio Files: No such file or directory
Moving ./[2013.04.05] - Audio - Academics - Course - Stephanie Hubach - Disability Ministry - /Drafts/[2013.04.05] - Audio - Academics - Course - Stephanie Hubach - Disability Ministry/Fade Files
mv: rename ./[2013.04.05] - Audio - Academics - Course - Stephanie Hubach - Disability Ministry - /Drafts/[2013.04.05] - Audio - Academics - Course - Stephanie Hubach - Disability Ministry/Fade Files to /Volumes/communications/Projects/Archived Projects/Academics/Fade Files: No such file or directory
Moving ./[2013.04.05] - Audio - Academics - Course - Stephanie Hubach - Disability Ministry - /Drafts/[2013.04.05] - Audio - Academics - Course - Stephanie Hubach - Disability Ministry/Session File Backups
mv: rename ./[2013.04.05] - Audio - Academics - Course - Stephanie Hubach - Disability Ministry - /Drafts/[2013.04.05] - Audio - Academics - Course - Stephanie Hubach - Disability Ministry/Session File Backups to /Volumes/communications/Projects/Archived Projects/Academics/Session File Backups: No such file or directory
Moving ./[2013.04.05] - Audio - Academics - Course - Stephanie Hubach - Disability Ministry - /Final
Moving ./[2013.04.05] - Audio - Academics - Course - Stephanie Hubach - Disability Ministry - /Source Files
Moving ./[2013.04.05] - Audio - Academics - Course - Stephanie Hubach - Disability Ministry - /Source Files/Copy
mv: rename ./[2013.04.05] - Audio - Academics - Course - Stephanie Hubach - Disability Ministry - /Source Files/Copy to /Volumes/communications/Projects/Archived Projects/Academics/Copy: No such file or directory
Moving ./[2013.04.05] - Audio - Academics - Course - Stephanie Hubach - Disability Ministry - /Source Files/Design
mv: rename ./[2013.04.05] - Audio - Academics - Course - Stephanie Hubach - Disability Ministry - /Source Files/Design to /Volumes/communications/Projects/Archived Projects/Academics/Design: No such file or directory
Moving ./[2013.04.05] - Audio - Academics - Course - Stephanie Hubach - Disability Ministry - /Source Files/RAW
mv: rename ./[2013.04.05] - Audio - Academics - Course - Stephanie Hubach - Disability Ministry - /Source Files/RAW to /Volumes/communications/Projects/Archived Projects/Academics/RAW: No such file or directory`

Comment: Let us see the exact code and errors as the /dest in your example cannot be produced from your code. Also how do you call the script

Comment: @Mark Here you go.

Comment: Shouldn't this be moved to Stackoverflow?

Comment: @CousinCocaine: From http://apple.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic: "We do encourage AppleScript, Automator, and UNIX shell scripting questions as well as how to use tools like Xcode for non-language specific tasks."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that all the folders to be archived are directly in `.../Completed Projects`, the use of `find` (which traverses the whole folder hierarchy) might actually do more harm than good.

A revised version could look like

```
#!/bin/bash

# Go to the Completed Projects folder.
cd /Volumes/communications/Projects/Completed\ Projects/

# Find a folder with a specified string (e.g. "Academics") in its name.
# Move (not copy) the folder to its corresponding sub-folder of the Archived Projects folder. (e.g. /Academics)

for folder in *; do
    if [[ -d "$folder" ]]; then
        echo "Moving $folder";
        if [[ "$folder" == *Academics* ]]; then
            mv "$folder" /Volumes/communications/Projects/Archived\ Projects/Academics/
        fi
    fi
done
```